# Encoding matter - ? instead of € after settings field callback

Tags: options, encoding, page-specific-settings

In my plugin I have som classes to manage settings field.

For some reason in one moment the setting field value with special characters like `30€` in `textarea` or `input[type=text]` change to be `30?`.

I got the value like this in my class :

```
add_action( "admin_init", array( $this, "init_options" ), 1 ); //$this is the Class

function init_options(){
  $this->current_options = get_option( $this->current_options_name );   
  $this->add_settings();
}
```

And before to add settings fields, the text is correctly encoded.

```
function add_settings(){
   ...
 $a_callback( ... ); //<--Set this current object with a method
 if( $field_title === "Terms and conditions" ){
     var_dump( $a_callback ); //At this moment, I can see in the object, current_options containing special caracters like '€'
 }               

   add_settings_field(
       $field_id, // ID
       __($field_title, $this->current_plugin_domain), // Title
       $a_callback, // Callback
       PAGE_SETTINGS, // Page in constant
       $section_id,// Section
       $args_field //args
   );
   ...
}
```

For the callback, for some reasons, I´m using the magic method [`__call ( string $name , array $arguments )`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) :

```
public function __call( $name, $arguments ){
        if( preg_match( " /^(setting_section_)([a-z\-]*)(_callback)$/", $name ) ){
            $this->print_section_info();
        }else if( preg_match( "/^([a-z\-_]*)(_callback)$/", $name ) ){
            foreach ( $arguments as $argument ){
                $args = [];
                $args['id']   = $argument['id'];
                $fieldType = $argument['type'];
                $args['section_slug']  = $argument['section_slug'];
                if( $args['id']  === "terms-conditions" ){
                    var_dump( $this->current_options['terms-conditions'] ); //here the char € was replaced by ?
                }
                ...
            }
        }
 }
```

So to get an overview to help a little more :

```
class Options{
    protected $current_options;
    public $options_names = array();
    public $options_group;
    public $current_options_name;
    
    public function __construct(...){
        add_action( "admin_init", array( $this, "init_options" ), 1 );
    }
    public function init_options(){
        foreach ( $this->options_names as $options_name ){
            register_setting(
                $this->options_group, // Option group
                $options_name, // Option name
                array( __CLASS__, "sanitize" ) // Sanitize
            );
        }
        $this->set_current_options();
        $this->add_settings();
   }

   protected function set_current_options(){
       $this->current_options = get_option( $this->current_options_name );
   }

   protected function add_settings(){
       ...
       $a_callback( ... ); //<--Set this current object with a method
       if( $field_title === "Terms and conditions" ){
          var_dump( $a_callback ); //At this moment, I can see in the object, current_options containing special caracters like '€'
       }               

       add_settings_field(
           $field_id, // ID
           __($field_title, $this->current_plugin_domain), // Title
           $a_callback, // Callback
           PAGE_SETTINGS, // Page in constant
           $section_id,// Section
           $args_field //args
       );
       ...
    }

    public function __call( $name, $arguments ){
        var_dump( $this->current_options['terms-conditions'] ); //text modified => special characters  modified by ?

    }
    
}
```

So, after the callback, there is a difference of encoding...

### Important notices

1. With the char `$`, I don´t have this problem, only with `€`.
2. if i do `var_dump( get_option( $this->current_options_name ) ); after` __call()`, I have the same problem so it seems to be link with` get_option()`

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Is your code in your Q complete? I've tried to read it but it's not obvious where or how the data is saved, or how `__call` is related to this ( or why it uses `__call` )

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes, it´s quite difficult. All functions are methods from the same class so $this is the instance of this class called `Options`

Comment: @TomJNowell I add an overview of the class.